# How does Liquibase Tag - commandline

Tags: liquibase

I was able to tag successfully using liquibase commandline, but do not know where it is tagged to and stored. The command was executed successfully, below is the input and response to the tag command.

This may be a very trivial question, but i could not find any documentation to it. I did try in its workspace - C:\liquibase-3.3.2-bin\sdk\workspace, could not find anything there. Can some one please help?

Thanks!

Input:

C:\liquibase-3.3.2-bin\liquibase.bat --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --classpath=C:\Microsoft_JDBC_Driver_SQL_Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc4.jar  --url="jdbc:sqlserver://DBServer:1433;databaseName=DBName" --username=DBUser --password=DBPassword --changeLogFile=D:\UDeployment\Liquibase\Stage\src\main\resources\db-changelog.xml tag test_25022015

Output:

Successfully tagged 
DBUser@jdbc:sqlserver://DBServer:1433;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=DBName;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;
Liquibase 'tag' Successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase create two tables in your database `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock`. All the scripts executed in the database will store the history in `databasechangelog`. When you ran `tag` process this mark the last script executed with the version you sent in the column `tag`.

Comment: Thanks @Eddú Meléndez , i was able to see the tag created in this table. But when i re-ran the tag for the same table. Say 1st tag is for creating the table and 2nd tag is for inserting some value. The tag got updated with a new value and did not create a new entry. The EXECTYPE is "RERAN" instead of "EXECUTED". How can i have both the tags?

Comment: If you have 3 script for the first iteration and you run liquibase tag task, then the third script will be mark with the tag. if you add 5 more scripts and then run liquibase tag task again the the last script (in this case 3 + 5 = 8) -script number 8- will be mark with the new tag.

Comment: Will the tag be created for the same table and dbchange log again? Below are the steps i did, but the tag get's overwritten everytime I run the tag command.

1) Create a Table
2) Insert 2 values to the table
3) Tag
4) Insert 2 values to the same table
5) Attempt Rollback

Comment: DB Change log - Insert Values


    <changeSet author="A1" id="1" runOnChange="true">

 <insert tableName="Test">

  <column name="NAME" value="Mark"/>

  <column name="GENDER" value="M"/>

  <column name="COUNTRY" value="USA"/>

 </insert>

 <insert tableName="Test7">

  <column name="NAME" value="Todd"/>

  <column name="GENDER" value="M"/>

  <column name="COUNTRY" value="USA"/>
 </insert>
 </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>

Comment: You have executed 2 scripts and the second one has been marked with te tag imagine version 1.0 then you apply a new script and finally rollback has been executed to back to version 1.0. Your database should have the state of version 1.0.

Comment: Yes, that's what i expected! unfortunately, the database rollback did not happen for step 2 - Insert first 2 values. The database was in its latest stage. Should i explicitly give any rollback script in dbchange log xml file?

Comment: I understand now. Yes, you have to add rollback script. You can see my demo project at https://github.com/eddumelendez/liquibase-demo

Comment: Thanks! i created a table similar to the demo, created a tag -tag_02032015. When i ran below query it said "Liquibase Rollback Successful", but i can still see the table existing. It is not dropped.


C:\liquibase-3.3.2-bin\liquibase.bat --driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --classpath=C:\Microsoft_JDBC_Driver_SQL_Server\sqljdbc_4.1\enu\sqljdbc4.jar  --url="jdbc:sqlserver://DBServer:1433;databaseName=DNName" --username=DBuser --password=DBPassword --changeLogFile=D:\Liquibase\Stage\src\main\resources\db-changelog.xml rollback tag_02032015

Comment: have you added the rollback script in your db-changelog.xml?

Comment: Yup..
 `<changeSet id="1" author="Amreth">

  <sqlFile path="001_create_role_table.sql"  encoding="UTF-8" />

  <rollback>

   <sqlFile path="rollback/001_drop_role_table.sql"
encoding="UTF-8" />
  </rollback>
 </changeSet>`

Comment: The db-changelog, 001_create_role_table and the rollback folder is in the same directory/ path.

Comment: I can see that you want to revert all the changes in the database, right? But, you have tagged your first script which is the last version you want to have. My advice is create the database, run the tag task from liquibase, execute update task and then tables will be created. Then apply rollback and table will be dropped. Take into account that tag is your last state it will not be deleted.

Comment: So, below are the steps i did

1) The database is already created.
2) Created a tag [ i believe, this tag is for the database]
3) Created a table
4) Created another tag [ i believe, this tag is for the database + tag]
5) Tried roll back with the tag created on step 2.

After step 5, the new table that was created should have been dropped.
My assumption is right?

Comment: Make sure your database is clear. I just to do this and works fine. Make sure tagname are different

Comment: Sure, will give it a shot. Thanks Eddú!

Comment: Hey Eddu, i created a new database and tried rollback [tag and changesheet]. but unsuccessful. Liquibase logs "Liquibase Rollback Successful" but no change in database. <br/>

1) Created a new database in MS SQL Server 2008 SP3 <br/>
2) Created a tag [new tag value] <br/>
3) Created a table <br/>
4) Tried rollback - tag, changesheet [values 1, 2] <br/>
5) Liquibase logs say "Liquibase Rollback Successful" but there is no change in database." <br/>

I use liquibase v3.3.2

Comment: Can you share your project sample in github, please? I have not used sqlserver instead I used mysql. But anyway, share your project and I will take a look.

Comment: Sure, i have added the codebase to https://github.com/amrethc/liquibase_mssql   thanks!

Comment: I can not see anything... make sure that after your commit you have push your commits to the central repository

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had issues with proxy and was not able to commit changes... i've added the project now. Hope you can view it.

Comment: First, rollback script is wrong table is not uDeploy_role (should be test_role) After that I did the steps tag, update, rollback and everything works fine. You can check more detail here https://github.com/amrethc/liquibase_mssql/issues/1

Comment: Hey Eddu, it was a typo.. i added a different file for drop table. I did use the right table name to drop... not sure if it a MS JDBC Driver issue to rollback? As i see the MS SQL driver works fine for you with the same command line arguments.

Comment: It could be a driver issue I think. Rollback works fine in mysql and postgres. My suggest is to use another driver like jtds http://jtds.sourceforge.net/. I think the question was answered so my support ends here.

Comment: Thanks!, Will check with this driver :)

Comment: Hey Eddu, tried with jtds... no luck! Everytime i run a rollback it says "Liquibase Rollback Successful", but it is actually not. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Command i used

`C:\liquibase-3.3.2-bin\liquibase.bat --driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --classpath=C:\jtds-1.3.1-dist\jtds-1.3.1.jar  --url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBServer:1433/DBName" --username=DBUser--password=DBPasswd --changeLogFile=changelog.xml rollback tag_123`

Comment: Have you tried using following my steps in mysql database? If it is works, something is wrong in liquibase when they work in mssql and you could report an issue.

Comment: Yup, tried your steps.. I even created a new database for this purpose!
I've logged an issue with liquibase - https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2279

Meanwhile, will continue to check on my end :)